# What are some common invalid forms in set theory and equational reasoning?

Tags: reference-request, formal-proofs

This is a reference recommendation.An argument is valid if it is impossible for the conclusion to be false and
premises be true.
a sentence form may be obtained
from a concrete sentence by replacing all the descriptive terms by letters, which
serve as place holders.I am asking for a  reference for errors in mathematical reasoniong.

Comment: No question is stated in the body of this post. There is a question in the title, but it's not a reference request as suggested in the body. In short, this question is badly in need of editing, to make it clear just what you are asking for.

Comment: I am asking for some kind of reference for errors in mathematical reasoning.

Comment: Then it should say that in the body of the question, please.

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/mathematical-fallacies/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy https://bsrlm.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/BSRLM-IP-27-3-01.pdf https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/j.ctt13x0nkj https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/scheines/80-110/lectures/feb3/feb3.htm